# Sci-fi book series, psychic family , 2010 plus or minus, instinctively know what to do

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi, psychic

I'm trying to remember a series I read maybe 5 to 10 years ago. The first book featured a young man who instinctively knew what to do to keep out of trouble. He goes through a series of adventures leading to a young woman (future wife) and learns he was being hunted (for recruitment) by a secret group of psychics.

I think near the beginning of the first book, the main character watches his house (or domicile) get blown up from a nearby hidden position.

Subsequent books feature next generations with superior talent. One of the later stars may have been named Rose but I'm not sure. The society is space flight capable, but I can't seem to recall much about that aspect.

It was US English language and not from translation.

I believe the first book was written 5-15 years ago. I read it in e-book form. I'm not certain there was a physical book published. I can't find it in my Amazon library; so it must have come from a free source.

Any ideas on series name or author?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a "space age series"? Does it include space travel, aliens, etc.? Or, do you mean it reads like it was written in the 1950s or 1960s?

Comment: The society was space flight capable. I think the first book was entirely on earth but after that, other planets may have been involved. Not horse and buggy like many fantasy series books I read. I think people in later books access an information network (like internet) via implants but I could be confusing it with another series.

Comment: It was written 5 to 15 years ago. I thought the editing was poor but stayed up most of the night to read. I read it in ebook form. Not sure if there was a hard or soft cover version.